# jquery code works once but not repeatedly

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, webgrid

i have a small jquery script that when I click an ajax actionlink in a grid/table(built from a webgrid) it will replace the contents with a spinning wheel.  It works the first time only.

```
$('#thisGrid tr td').click(function () {
    $(this).html('<img  src="@Url.Content("~/Content/ajax-loader.gif")" alt="Loading... Please Wait" style="height: 20px;"/>');
});
```

I have not found anything that has led me to determine why this is so... Any thoughts on why this might be happening?

Comment: Consider that the click handlers may need to be wired up again to any new `#thisGrid tr td` present in the ajax'ed html. Use jQuery `on` to do this.

Comment: I tried using the 'on' method but it throws an error saying it doesnt support the method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Delegate** the event

```
$('#thisGrid').on('click','td' , function () {
    $(this).html('<img  src="@Url.Content("~/Content/ajax-loader.gif")"
                alt="Loading... Please Wait" style="height: 20px;"/>');
});
```

**UPDATE**  For jQuery 1.6 and below

```
 $('#thisGrid').delegate('td' , 'click', function () {
        $(this).html('<img  src="@Url.Content("~/Content/ajax-loader.gif")"
                    alt="Loading... Please Wait" style="height: 20px;"/>');
    });
```

Comment: I tried this but it errors saying it doesnt support the method 'on'

Comment: What is the jQuery version you are using in your project

Comment: If that the case you  can .delegate as in the post above

Comment: I tried the 'delegate' and got the same results... I got ahold of 1.7 and tried the 'on' and got the same results.  It works the first time but not thereafter.  I need to check the _layout... i may have conflicting scripts....

Answer (score 1):

Possibly try using a live click function.

```
$('#thisGrid tr td').live('click', function(){ ...
```

Comment: this does not appear to work... just blanks the content area.